# I'm trying to make a react native app that is able to open Spotify and play a song

Tags: react-native, spotify, applinks

I have an app that i would like to connect to spotify so when my user pushes a button it will search in spotify for a song/playlist with predefined parameters that i will set. For example i will have two buttons one for hip-hop and the other for country. Once the user pushes a button I would like to redirect them to spotify and search the corresponding button title and maybe play the song. Similar to what shazam does to discovered songs you search on the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Spotify has a pretty mighty sdk and you should use it. To be able to access all features you need to use their SDK on native side. The topic is too big to answer it here via Stackoverflow.**

*React-Native native Module Guide for Android -*
[React-Native - Android Modules](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html)

*React-Native native Module Guide for iOS -*
[React-Native - iOSModules](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html)

*Spotify's Android SDK Guide -*
[Android](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/tutorial/)

*Spotify's iOS SDK Guide -*
[iOS](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/tutorial/)

Comment: I see here that you linked an iOS SDK and an Android SDK. And the iOS SDK uses Xcode. Isn’t that exclusively on macs? I don’t own a Mac. And I’m guessing I will have to make to versions of my app for both iOS and android seeing that they both have different instructions, is that correct?

Comment: You are right. From my side I didnt experience a "mac free" solution yet. If you find some > Tell me please :)

But if you do it right, your React-Native code just has to be written once, which calls your native modules. Only the implementation for that app call with the api hand over has to be done for every plattform seperately.

Comment: And what are your thoughts on deep linking? I know I can link to other apps but could I possibly link to a url that contains a desired search parameter within the linked app?

Comment: What they are doing in their documentation is using deep linking (Spotify - docs). As far as i know there is no implemented way in React-Native to make it happen without going native like you can see in the following link: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html

Comment: One year ago I had to implement the same behavior for VanillaNav - an indoor navigation - and they had a very easy and usefull documentation about using a deeplink to open their app and send several informations to it.

[Android]: http://www.vanillanav.com/faq/index.php?sid=46987&lang=en&action=artikel&cat=5&id=19&artlang=en

Maybe you feel more comfortable with this documentation.